# Why I dont't can see the Layout from a Android Application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

hi i get a error in my android application if I use this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the error that i see if I want to see the layout in the Graphical Layout:

```
Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

here my version

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: You probably selected Android 4.4W (API 20) in the Preview-Window of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use EditText on 4.4W. Change the API to 19 or less if you are not downloaded API 19 then you can download API level 19 from SDK Manager.